# Stat command to shortlist files with change date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

When we run `stat filename` we get

```
Access: 2021-06-25 15:40:18.532621916 +0530
Modify: 2020-08-13 15:57:30.000000000 +0530
Change: 2021-06-25 14:17:20.209432991 +0530
```

I have 100 files in a directory, now i only want to shortlist files with change date 2021-06-23 using stat command.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over your files and check the date. If the date matches, print the file. Directories are excluded by checking for files explicitly (`[[ -f "$f" ]]`).

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in *; do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ "$(stat -c%z "$f")" == *2021-06-23* ]]; then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In a pipeline, with only one call to stat:

```sh
stat -c '%F %z %n' -- * | grep '^regular file 2021-06-23' | cut -d ' ' -f 6-
```

If the directory only contains plain files

```sh
stat -c '%z %n' -- * | grep '^2021-06-23' | cut -d ' ' -f 4-
```